# Android get click position from within OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

How do I get the following information when the user click on my list view?

- Reference to selected item
- The click coordinates or the TouchEvent object

I don't have the option to catch the click from the adapter, the API that I use prevent me from doing so.

i do have control over the creation of the view itself.

Is there a way for me to get the click position of view from OnItemClickListener?

Comment: As per documentation: `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) --> `position`

Comment: @Trinimon sorry it not what I meant, I need the x,y position of the click.

Comment: onTouchListener then,

Comment: @Blackbelt how do you get ITEM view from onTouch listener?

Comment: Do you have access to ArrayList that ListView is filled with?

Comment: @AhmadEbrahimi yeah, My actual problem is that the view is mapped to several items in the ArrayList and I need the x,y position of the click to figure out to where it belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `OnTouchListener` for this:

```
private int positionX;
private int positionY;

getListView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    positionX = (int)event.getX();
    positionY = (int)event.getY();
    return false; // not consumed; forward to onClick
  }
});

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Item position: " +position);
    Log.d("TAG", "Screen X: " +positionX);
    Log.d("TAG", "Screen Y: " +positionY);
    ...
  }
});
```

***Note***: if you would like to have the coordinates in the `OnItemClickListener`, store the positions in private members of the `ListView`. This works because `onTouch` is invoked before `onItemClick`

Comment: How do you get reference to the view item it clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want? 
Touch coordinates?

use:

```
YourListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();    
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Coordinates: " + x + " , "+ y, Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you get reference to the view it been clicked on?

Comment: ah thats what you want? you want the coordinates of the item you selected?